# How to add more columns in SISS Slowly Changing Dimension Wizard?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I've been working on an ETL process with a source table that has 90 columns and now I want to set each of the columns as a changing attribute in the Slow Changing Dimensions Wizard, but I can't add all the table columns to set them, only 27 of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD) Wizard in SSIS, there is a known limitation where only the first 27 columns are displayed for selection as changing attributes. This limitation exists in some versions of SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS), including SQL Server 2017 and earlier.

So instead of relying on the SCD Wizard, you need to configure the Slowly Changing Dimension transformations in SSIS manually. Try to use components such as Conditional Split, Derived Column, and Lookup to compare the values in the source and destination tables for each column and determine which columns have changed.

Another option is to use a Script Component in SSIS to handle the SCD logic. You can write custom code to compare each column's source and destination values and determine if they have changed. This gives you complete control over the SCD logic and allows you to handle all 90 columns as changing attributes.